# Is literal ellipsis really valid as ParamSpec last argument?

Tags: python, python-typing, type-variables

Quote from [Python docs for `Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate):

> The last parameter to Concatenate must be a ParamSpec or ellipsis (...).

I know what `ParamSpec` is, but the ellipsis here drives me mad. It is [not accepted](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=65a3d076ae29e2cbe24a500165d76126) by `mypy`:

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, Concatenate, TypeVar, Generic

_P = ParamSpec('_P')
_T = TypeVar('_T')


class Test(Generic[_P, _T]):
    fn: Callable[Concatenate[_P, ...], _T]
```

```
E: Unexpected "..." [misc]
E: The last parameter to Concatenate needs to be a ParamSpec  [valid-type]
```

and is not explained anywhere in docs. [PEP612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#the-components-of-a-paramspec) doesn't mention it. Is it just a mistake, appeared as a result of mixing `Callable` and `Concatenate` together?

[This issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88954) is somewhat related and shows syntax with ellipsis literal in `Concatenate`:

> The specification should be extended to allow either `Concatenate[int, str, ...]`, or `[int, str, ...]`, or some other syntax.

But this clearly targets "future syntax".

Note: I'm aware of meaning of ellipsis as `Callable` argument, this question is specifically about `Concatenate`.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet for which you get this error?

Comment: Oh, there's a link to mypy playground. Could you copy the code snippet to the post as well?

Comment: The last argument to `Concatenate` must be one or the other, but that doesn't necessarily imply that `...` can *precede* `ParamSpec`.

Comment: The documentation mentions `Concatenate[Arg1Type, Arg2Type, ..., ParamSpecVariable]`, but I think that's not a literal `...`, but rather an indication that you can list one or more concrete types followed by a `ParamSpec`. (`Concatenate[Arg1Type, _P]`, `Concatenate[Arg1Type, Arg2Type, _P]`, etc.)

Comment: Hm, the support for the ellipsis type has been introduced only in April this year https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30969

Comment: I've summarized what I have found in an answer below. Perhaps it's worth creating an issue in mypy about that.

Comment: @chepner You're right, but `mypy` doesn't allow ellipsis as last `Concatenate` type argument - doesn't matter what precedes it, `ParamSpec` or regular type like `int`.

Comment: @PawełRubin `mypy` issue should be based on some proofs from python documentation, IMO. I'll open it as well, but I'd rather begin with issue on python tracker - this should be mentioned in docs somewhere, ideally - backed by PEP with implementation and behaviour details. `mypy` follows general recommendations to be PEP-compatible, so they have to exist before `mypy` support is introduced.

Comment: [`mypy` issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14656) was raised too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PEP-612's grammar](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#valid-use-locations), the ellipsis is not permitted in the `Concatenate` expression:

> We now augment that with two new options: a parameter specification variable (`Callable[P, int]`) or a concatenation on a parameter specification variable (`Callable[Concatenate[int, P], int]`).

```
callable ::= Callable "[" parameters_expression, type_expression "]"

parameters_expression ::=
  | "..."
  | "[" [ type_expression ("," type_expression)* ] "]"
  | parameter_specification_variable
  | concatenate "["
                   type_expression ("," type_expression)* ","
                   parameter_specification_variable
                "]"
```

> where `parameter_specification_variable` is a `typing.ParamSpec` variable, declared in the manner as defined above, and `concatenate` is `typing.Concatenate`.

However, the support for ellipsis as the last argument for Concatenate [was introduced in April 2022](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30969) as part of Python 3.11.

No type checker seems to handle this new case though.

Comment: Aha, thanks! So, basically `Concatenate[int, ...]` describes arguments of function that accepts an `int` as first positional arg and anything else (possibly empty set or some args/kwards) after that, similar to `Callable[..., None]` which can accept arbitrary arguments?